# How do I edit through inspect element, but when I click on submit it won't make any changes?

Tags: laravel

When I open the website I need to fill in the form. I already disabled some field from editing, so the user is not able to change the information on the form. However, the user can still right-click and update through the inspect element and when the user clicks submit, the data will be submitted and updated. So now what I want to do is, even after the user edit through the inspect element, but when the user clicks on submit, the data won't pass through and there will be no changes. In order to do this, what do I change in the coding? These are the attachments of the merchant request form and the merchant controller.

MerchantRequest

[image]

MerchantController

[image]

Comment: server side validation? show us some code.

Comment: "the user can still right-click and update through the inspect element and when the user clicks submit, the data will be submitted and updated." That's why you validate in the back end.

Comment: @sumitwadhwa its the MerchantRequest.php file right? the one that I posted as an attachment.

Comment: @IGP but what do I add in the coding?